# How to set screen resolution without having a monitor connected?

Tags: c#, winapi, screen-resolution

In my company, we sometimes use surface automation to automate our processes. That means, that the program is searching for images on the screen and is clicking them, for example:

We're developing using a screen resolution of `2560 x 1440`. We have many computers working there for us - and not all of them are always connected to a monitor. When I disconnect the monitor, windows is changing the resolution to `1024 x 768`. **I'd like to avoid that**. In the internet, I read about the tool NirCmd - but it's not so easy for me to use such a tool in my big, conservative company and I wonder, if there is a possibility with C#.

I found a solution working perfectly - but only, if a monitor is connected (find the code at the end of this request). **Is there a possibility to change the resolution even if there is no monitor connected?** Or is there a possibility to define the resolution once and for all, windows is using without having a screen connected? This is not working for me:
https://superuser.com/questions/604026/how-to-set-default-screen-resolution-and-color-depth-without-monitor-in-windows

Code that works fine - but only, if a screen is connected:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct DEVMODE1
{
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 32)]
    public string dmDeviceName;
    public short dmSpecVersion;
    public short dmDriverVersion;
    public short dmSize;
    public short dmDriverExtra;
    public int dmFields;

    public short dmOrientation;
    public short dmPaperSize;
    public short dmPaperLength;
    public short dmPaperWidth;

    public short dmScale;
    public short dmCopies;
    public short dmDefaultSource;
    public short dmPrintQuality;
    public short dmColor;
    public short dmDuplex;
    public short dmYResolution;
    public short dmTTOption;
    public short dmCollate;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 32)]
    public string dmFormName;
    public short dmLogPixels;
    public short dmBitsPerPel;
    public int dmPelsWidth;
    public int dmPelsHeight;

    public int dmDisplayFlags;
    public int dmDisplayFrequency;

    public int dmICMMethod;
    public int dmICMIntent;
    public int dmMediaType;
    public int dmDitherType;
    public int dmReserved1;
    public int dmReserved2;

    public int dmPanningWidth;
    public int dmPanningHeight;
};

class User_32
{
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern int EnumDisplaySettings(string deviceName, int modeNum, ref DEVMODE1 devMode);
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern int ChangeDisplaySettings(ref DEVMODE1 devMode, int flags);

    public const int ENUM_CURRENT_SETTINGS = -1;
    public const int CDS_UPDATEREGISTRY = 0x01;
    public const int CDS_TEST = 0x02;
    public const int DISP_CHANGE_SUCCESSFUL = 0;
    public const int DISP_CHANGE_RESTART = 1;
    public const int DISP_CHANGE_FAILED = -1;
}

public static class ScreenResolution
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Ändert die Bildschirmauflösung in die gewünschte Größe
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="width"></param>
    /// <param name="height"></param>
    public static void ChangeResolution(int width, int height)
    {
        Screen screen = Screen.PrimaryScreen;

        int iWidth = width;
        int iHeight = height;

        DEVMODE1 dm = new DEVMODE1();
        dm.dmDeviceName = new String(new char[32]);
        dm.dmFormName = new String(new char[32]);
        dm.dmSize = (short)Marshal.SizeOf(dm);

        if (0 != User_32.EnumDisplaySettings(null, User_32.ENUM_CURRENT_SETTINGS, ref dm))
        {
            dm.dmPelsWidth = iWidth;
            dm.dmPelsHeight = iHeight;

            int iRet = User_32.ChangeDisplaySettings(ref dm, User_32.CDS_TEST);

            if (iRet == User_32.DISP_CHANGE_FAILED)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Unable to process your request");
                MessageBox.Show("Description: Unable To Process Your Request. Sorry For This Inconvenience.", "Information", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
            }
            else
            {
                iRet = User_32.ChangeDisplaySettings(ref dm, User_32.CDS_UPDATEREGISTRY);

                switch (iRet)
                {
                    case User_32.DISP_CHANGE_SUCCESSFUL:
                        {
                            break;
                            //successfull change
                        }
                    case User_32.DISP_CHANGE_RESTART:
                        {
                            MessageBox.Show("Description: You Need To Reboot For The Change To Happen.\n If You Feel Any Problem After Rebooting Your Machine\nThen Try To Change Resolution In Safe Mode.", "Information", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
                            break;
                            //windows 9x series you have to restart
                        }
                    default:
                        {
                            MessageBox.Show("Description: Failed To Change The Resolution.", "Information", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
                            break;
                            //failed to change
                        }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I suggest that you find a solution in C++, and then translate. Trying to work this out with the added complexity of p/invoke is just a recipe for slow painful progress, and erroneous conclusions.

Comment: when you run this are you running it as a user or "as Administrator"?

Comment: Yes, I did so. As I said, if a monitor is connected, it's working. Only if there is no monitor connected, he's giving me a message, that he cannot change the resolution. I wrote a programm, writing the screen resolution to the console each second. After 10 seconds, he is executing the function to change the resolution. I run it as administrator and then, I disconnect the monitor. When i reconnect it I can see, that he downscaled the resolution.

Answer (score 0):

To change the screen resolution programaticaly use [ChangeDisplaySettings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd183411(v=vs.85).aspx)().

Syntax:

```
LONG ChangeDisplaySettings(
  _In_ DEVMODE *lpDevMode,
  _In_ DWORD   dwflags
);
```

Comment: I'm still doing that.

Comment: Did this work @Jan021981? Are you still looking for a solution? If not, what is the solution?

Answer (score 0):

If a hardware solution is possible for you, you can use a device called video edid (yes, correct spelled). It is a small dongle of the size of a memory stick that is put between the graphics card and the video cable. It simulates a running screen to the operating system so it always keeps the last resolution. Google for "video edid" and you will find products for about $20